# cauchy's integral formula in operator theory

Tags: operator-theory, banach-spaces, spectral-theory, banach-algebras

Can you prove cauchy's integral formula based on the assumptions in Conway book, operator theory, VII, 4.2?

> **4.2. Cauchy's Integral Formula** If $\mathcal X$ is a Banach space, $G$ is an open subset of $\mathbb C$, $f : G \to \mathcal X $ is analytic, $\gamma$ is a closed rectifiable curve in $G$ such that $n(\gamma;a)=0$ for every $a \in \mathbb C\setminus G$, and $\lambda \in G \setminus \{\gamma\}$, then for every integer $k\geq 0$,
>   $$
> n(\gamma;\lambda)f^{(k)}(\lambda) = \frac{k!}{2\pi i} \int_\gamma (z-\lambda)^{-(k+1)}f(z)dz
> $$

Comment: Depends on what those assumptions _are_...

Comment: Exactly what we have  above.

Answer (score 3):

This is immediate from the definitions, plus the ordinary scalar-valued Cauchy's Integral Formula.

Suppose $\Lambda\in X^*$, and let $g=\Lambda\circ f$. So $g$ is analytic (by definition or not, depending on which definition of "analytic" you took). CIF shows that $$\Lambda(n(\gamma;\lambda)f(\lambda))=n(\gamma;\lambda)g(\lambda)=\frac1{2\pi i}\int_\gamma\frac{g(z)\,dz}{z-\lambda}=\frac1{2\pi i}\int_\gamma\frac{\Lambda\circ f(z)\,dz}{z-\lambda},$$and *by definition* this shows that
$$n(\gamma;\lambda)f(\lambda))=\frac1{2\pi i}\int_\gamma\frac{f(z)\,dz}{z-\lambda},$$which is what you want for $k=0$.

For $k>0$ it's the same, after you prove by induction that $$g^{(k)}=\Lambda\circ f^{(k)}.$$

Comment: Seems to me that one needs to prove [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1848182/banach-space-valued-analytic-functions) first to prove by induction that $g^{(k)}=\Lambda\circ f^{(k)}$. Am I right ?

Comment: I was assuming that the definition of "$f$ is analytic" was the existence of $f'$ as a limit in norm. If that's the definition then no, it follows just from linearity and continuity of $\Lambda$. If the definition is as in that other thread, namely that $\Lambda\circ f$ is analytic for every $\Lambda$ then yes, you need to show this implies strong differentiability first, so that we know there _is_ such a thing as $f'$. Of course if you look at recent activity in that other thread you see it's simpler than we thought yesterday...

Comment: @LeoSera The OP here never clarified the definition of "analytic". I see you've quoted Conway's definition in that other thread. With that definition then no, we don't need anything, it follows just from linearity and continuity of $\Lambda$. We're given that $(f(z+h)-f(z))/h\to f'(z)$ in norm. Hence $(g(z+h)-g(z))/h=\Lambda((f(z+h)-f(z))/h)\to\Lambda(f'(z))$.