# Banach-Space-Valued Analytic Functions

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, analytic-functions

This is Chapter VII, $\S$3, exercise 4, from Conway's book: A Course in Functional Analysis:

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $G\subset \mathbb{C}$ an open subset. We say that $f: G \to X$ is **analytic** if the limit $$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{ f(z+h)-f(z)}{h}$$ exist in $X$ for all $z \in G$.

> Prove that if $f: G \to X$ is a function such that for each $x^* \in X^*$, the function $x^*\circ f : G \to \mathbb{C}$ is analytic (in the usual way), then $f$ is **analytic**.

Since weak convergence does not imply the strong one, I feel that I am missing something to prove this. Any thoughts? Thanks in advance.

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1672711/x-circ-fg-rightarrow-bbbc-is-analytic-show-f-is-analytic?rq=1) could be helpful

Comment: cool, I knew we needed uniform boundedness, but I would never think using the Cauchy integral formula @NateRiver

Comment: @NateRiver Thanks Nate, I've just seen that question too, however it seems that the answer is proving that $f$ must by strongly continuous at $0$, I don´t know how that implies that $f$ is analytic :(

Comment: @user1952009 I am actually trying to do it with uniform boundedness, since Conway's book asks this exercise before introducing Banach space integrals, thus I want to avoid Cauchy Integral Formula. Any hints?

Comment: ? you need both ${}{}$

Comment: I'm not convinced you can avoid the Cauchy integral Formula, that is useful for linking $\sup_{|h| < r} \|x^*\|\, \|f(z)\| $ to $\sup_{|h| < r}\left|\frac{x^*(f(z+h))-x^*(f(z))}{h}\right|$

Comment: @user1952009 Oh right the scalar valued Cauchy integral Formula!! For a moment I thought on the Banach valued Cauchy integral Formula. So sorry for the confusion, my bad… The thing is that Rudin Functional Analysis 3.31, actually uses the Banach valued Cauchy integral Formula to conclude that $f$ is analytic, and that is what I want to avoid.

Comment: @Leo Sera Sorry. Does that definition of analyticity that you give appear in Conway's book? On what page?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We give the proof the OP wants, also an example showing that the result fails for functions on the line.

The standard proof via the vector-valued Cauchy Integral Formula seems like the "right" proof, because that vector-valued CIF is going to be fundamentally important soon anyway, when we get to Banach algebras and operator theory and so on. But, if we want a proof that we can do  before we get to vector-valued integrals, here it is. Doesn't use Uniforrm Boundedness either; uses nothing but Hahn-Banach on the Banach space side.

Say $\overline{D(z,r)}\subset G$. Say $0<\delta<r/2$ and $|s|,|t|\in(0,\delta)$. If $x^*\in X^*$ with $||x^*||\le1$ then CIF applied to $x^*\circ f$ shows that $$\left|x^*\left(\frac{f(z+s)-f(z)}{s}-\frac{f(z+t)-f(z)}{t}\right)\right|\le c\delta\sup_{|w-z|=r}|x^*(f(w))|
\le c\delta\sup_{|w-z|=r}||f(w)||.$$The right side is independent of $x^*$; we sneak in a $\sup_{||x^*||\le1}$ on the left side and we obtain
$$\lim_{s,t\to0}\left|\left|\frac{f(z+s)-f(z)}{s}-\frac{f(z+t)-f(z)}{t}\right|\right|=0.$$

---

**Free Bonus** An example of $f:\Bbb R\to X$ such that $x^*\circ f$ is $C^1$ for every $x^*\in X^*$ although $f$ is not differentiable in norm, showing that there *has* to be *something* "complex" about the proof of the result above:

Define $f:\Bbb R\to c_0$ by $$f(t)=\left(e^{it},\frac12 e^{2it},
\frac13e^{3it},\dots\right).$$If $x^*\in X^*=\ell^1$ then dominated convergence shows that $x^*\circ f$ is $C^1$. On the other hand, it's  clear that $$f'(t)=\left(ie^{it},ie^{2it},\dots\right)$$is the derivative of $f$ in *some* sense (for example in the sense of weak* convergence in $c_0^{**}$); if $f$ *were* differentiable in norm the derivative would be the $f'$ above, but $f'(t)\notin c_0$.

I *suspect* that there is no such example with $X$ reflexive.

[...]

**No wait,** there's a simple example in a Hilbert space. (In the example above you may note that $||f'(t)||_{c_o^{**}}$ is constant. This was why I couldn't find the Hilbert space example. As soon as I realized that, in a Hilbert space, if $t\mapsto f'(t)$ is weakly continuous but not norm continuous then $||f'(t))||$ cannot be continuous the example fell right out.)

Define $f:\Bbb R\to L^2(\Bbb R)$ by setting $f(t)=0$ for $t\le0$, while for $t>0$ $$f(t)(x)=\begin{cases}0,&(x\le 0),
\\(t^{1/2}-x^{1/2})^+,&(x>0).\end{cases}$$We leave the details to the reader, since this post is long enough already. Two hints: The weak derivative comes out to $$f'(t)=\begin{cases}0,&(t\le0),\\
\frac{t^{-1/2}}{2}\chi_{(0,t)},&(t>0),\end{cases}$$and in verifying that $f$ is not differentiable  in norm you can avoid an argument that requires the numbers to come out just right by noting that$$\left|\left|\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}-f'(0)\right|\right|= \left|\left|\frac{f(h)}{h}\right|\right|=||f(1)||\quad(h>0).$$

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Double Thanks !

Comment: @LeoSera It's actually much simpler than I thought.