# If all compositions of a vector-valued function with its linear functionals are analytic, is the function itself analytic?

Tags: functional-analysis, analytic-functions, dual-spaces

This is taken from Conway's *A course in functional Analysis* (p. 198, Exercise 4):

Let $\mathscr{X}$ be a Banach space and $G \subset \mathbb{C}$ open. If $f: G \rightarrow \mathscr{X}$ is such that for each $x^{*} \in \mathscr{X}^{*}$, $(x^{*} \circ f): G \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is analytic, prove $f$ is analytic itself. If the word "continuous" is substituted for both occurrences of the word "analytic", is the preceding statement still true?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Would this answer your question? [Banach-Space-Valued Analytic Functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1848182)

Comment: @BrunoB Thanks so much, I feel stupid I couldn't find this myself...